# how to pop when first pushed vc then presented modal vc 12 times?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have a navigation controller. I first pushed a VC, then presented 12 modals VC's. Now I want to pop to root viewController. How can I do that? Please help me out.

Comment: If you have navigation controller, if you want to use the `popToViewController` technique to jump back multiple controllers, then you should be using `pushViewController` (or push segues) not `presentViewController` (or modal segues).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to dismiss the 12 modal views that you have presented. popViewController or popToRootViewController will not work.

Comment: But how can I do that Its my Question

Comment: @JunaidSidhu: dismiss your presented view controllers. You will need to handle this in code by yourself as it seems from your question that the user wont be the one dismissing the views or is it?

Comment: As an afterthought, why dont you push the views instead of showing them modally? You can totally eliminate this problem by doing popToRootViewController.

Comment: Kevin, I agree that it's to contort yourself to dismiss multiple modals, but it's just plain silly. @JunaidSidhu should just be pushing to the next view controller, not doing modals. And if Junaid doesn't want the navigation bar to show up on those children, it can be hidden `[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];`

Comment: I second that, beats me why one would present so many modals.

Answer (score 2):

Dismiss your modal views to get to the root view.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I am not sure I do understand your question correctly.
But is UINavigationController's 
- (NSArray *)popToRootViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated
what you are searching for?

Comment: Can you perhaps rephrase your question and elaborate on who pushes what when and so on? To me, it is a bit unclear what you are actually aiming to achieve.

Comment: I have a navigation controller, I first push it to an other controller , then present 12 Controllers on that Controller, now I want to go back to the first one.

Comment: Ok, that's something completely different. As I said - I did not get your question initially.

Answer (score 0):

If you have navigation controller and want to enjoy the benefits of popping back multiple levels in a single command, then you should be using `pushViewController` (or push segues) not `presentViewController` (or modal segues).

As others have pointed out, if you were correcting pushing to the subsequent controllers, then you could pop back via:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Tell the pushed VC to `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:`. This will dismiss *all* the presented VCs. Now you can pop the pushed VC.

Answer (score 0):

Keep a first NavigationController in an instance variable of AppDelegate. In AppDelegate.h

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UINavigationController *navigationControllerFirst;
```

In the RootViewController viewDidLoad add the following.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    AppDelegate *app = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    app.navigationControllerFirst = self.navigationController;
}
```

Then, to achieve what you wanted, in the 12th presented modal add the following function to go back to RootViewController.

```
- (IBAction)GoToHome:(id)sender {
    AppDelegate *app = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [app.navigationControllerFirst dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        [app.navigationControllerFirst popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }];
}
```