# model presenting 12 viewControllers and now dismiss to a specfic VC, how can I do that

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to pop when first pushed vc then presented modal vc 12 times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13661388/how-to-pop-when-first-pushed-vc-then-presented-modal-vc-12-times)

I am model (presenting) 12 viewControllers and now I want to dismiss to a specfic VC, how can I do that. please help me out.

Comment: Repost of [how to pop, When 1st pust then model 12times?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13661388/how-to-pop-when-1st-pust-then-model-12times)

Comment: Best to not do it modal, but use navigation controller, as implied by your other, duplicative question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13661388/how-to-pop-when-1st-pust-then-model-12times

Comment: Its not working in both cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it in one step, then you have to call dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion: from the controller you want to go back to. That will dismiss all the controllers that were presented after it in the chain. If you need to do this from a button click (or other user interaction) in that last controller that was presented, then you might have to send an NSNotification that the controller you want to go back to, listens for, and acts on to dismiss all the controllers.

Answer (score 1):

Dismiss your modal views to reach root view

Answer (score 0):

you can dismiss as many controllers like below, for example: below code will dismiss 2 viewcontrollers, just add parentviewontroller:

```
[[self parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:animated]; //dismiss 2 viewcontrollers

[[self parentViewController] parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:animated]; //dismiss 3 viewcontrollers
```

Check this out : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cKV5csbueHA